# Java 2d array, test for square

Tags: java

I'm given an array (a2d) and I need to determine if every row and column has the same number of elements as every other row and column. If it is then I set the Boolean isSquare to true.

I have come up with the following code, but it doesn't like it and it isn't giving me any suggestions on how to improve it.

```
for(int row = 0; row < a2d.length; row++){
for(int col = 0; col < a2d[row].length; col++)
    if(a2d.length == a2d[row].length)
        isSquare = true;
    else
        isSquare = false;
}
```

Am I testing this the wrong way or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for 2 loops you should be able to do something like this (I'm not going to give the code since it's homework)

```
1. Save the length of the array (a2d.length)
2. Loop over all the rows
3. Check to see if the given row has the same length
4. if Not return false 
5. if you reach the end of the loop return true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0, l = a2d.length; i < l; i++) {
  if (a2d[i].length != l) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

You just need to ensure that all of the lengths of the 2nd dimension arrays are the same length as the first dimension array.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a2d.length == a2d[row].length)
    isSquare = true;
else
    isSquare = false;
```

If the last element passes this will return true always. Try this:

```
isSquare = true;
for(int row = 0; row < a2d.length; row++){
for(int col = 0; col < a2d[row].length; col++)
    if(a2d.length != a2d[row].length)
        isSquare = false;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to loop over every column it doesn't change the if statement

Comment: I think that was the main issue, it was returning true when not all the elements passed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the length of the array (size.length)
2. Loop over all the rows
3. Check to see if the given row has the same length
4. Set isSquare if true go on otherwise false, to controll the loop
5. if you reach the end of the loop and isSquare
   return true otherwise false

   ```
   private static boolean isSquare(Object[][] matrix){
   boolean isSquare = true;
   //Save the length of the array
   int size = matrix.length;

   //Loop over all the rows and Check to see if the given row has the same length
    for (int i = 0; i < size && isSquare; i++) {
       isSquare = size == matrix[i].length;
    }
   return isSquare;
   }
   ```

or not puristic with fori

```
private static boolean isSquare(Object[][] matrix){
    //Save the length of the array
    int size = matrix.length;

    //Loop over all the rows and Check to see if the given row has the same length
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(size != matrix[i].length)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

with enhanced for

```
private static boolean isSquare(Object[][] matrix){
    //Save the length of the array
    int size = matrix.length;

    //Loop over all the rows and Check to see if the given row has the same length
    for (Object[] objects : matrix) {
        if (size != objects.length)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: I guess now it´s better explained otherwise ask again. @Tyler2P But I got your point. This answer is puristic but also a solution by using the java garbage collector is possible. I think that in this case the puristic salution is prettier.